# How to prevent server blocking php

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, real-time, daemon

I'm currently developing a php daemon for connecting and retreiving data from social networks like facebook and twitter. This script allready works but I have some concerns about it.

It's possible to create an infinite amount of accounts that the script has to process and (right now) it runs every 5 minutes to create a 'near' realtime experience. So my concern is that, when, let's say 5000 accounts, have been created and have to be monitored. The script slows down and maybe wil run longer than the 5 minute interval. Is there any way to work around this problem? And better, is there any good way (with php, possible with javascript) to create a better 'near' realtime experience?

Any advice will be great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you might have a page that shows updates on 5000 FaceBook accounts all at once?  Do you need to update all of them at once, or could you show some subset of the accounts and update only those?

Comment: Is this script running in a browser window with user interaction or is it something in the background like a cronjob?

If it's in the browser it sounds like a job for ajax.  You can create similar 'real-time' interfaces by setting ajax events to setTimeout so that every five seconds or so the window will check for new posts.  Is this something like what you mean?

Comment: It's in the background with a cronjob process. I might have 5000 facebook accounts which status updates have to be pulled in and processed. So with more accounts, the script runs longer.

Comment: How ddo you output the results? is this a commandline script or are you running it on a webserver?

Comment: The results are loaded into the database in the background. The results are displayed via ajax to the user. This already works great. It's the background process that botters me

Comment: Where are you getting you cache of FB userids?  Are they in a database?  If so, one approach I could think of is to have the cronjob only run for about 100 ids each iteration, and have it save the last id to a textfile where it can pick up over the next iteration.  Once it finished all the ids, it could record a stop signal that would then tell the system to start over on the next iteration.  This would mean you get all the updates over a slightly long period of time.  Is this something you'd be interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for most sites you can retrieve a stream containing all that data(in real-time). For example:

### 1. twitter

> [site streams](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/site_streams) allows services,
>   such as web sites or mobile push
>   services, to receive real-time updates
>   for a large number of users without
>   any of the hassles of managing REST
>   API rate limits

### 2. Facebook

> The Graph API supports [real-time](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime)
>   updates to enable your application
>   using Facebook to subscribe to changes
>   in data from Facebook.

When using these streams you can process the streams in real-time and don't have to do no(nearly none) polling.

P.S: I would most definitely code this in node.js.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to spawn multiple daemons and share duties between them. Perhaps have single central job queue and have the daemons consume that. It's really a server-side issue and Javascript has very little to do with such tasks, as long it's not server-side JS.

If the number of monitored subjects is going into thousands, PHP is not really a viable choice since it's neither inherently multi-threaded nor does it have synchronization features. In mass monitoring scenarios, a dedicated server running a J2EE, .NET or a custom multithreaded application is pretty much a must.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Saul. Would you recommend something like Tornado ? http://www.tornadoweb.org/

Comment: actually PHP does a decent job, but spawning this thread every 5 minutes is a bad ideea. It would be more suitable a server-client design, where the client requests something and the server fetches and caches things 5 minutes at a time..

Comment: @Quamis - Question of opinion - would you recommend using actual user traffic to fire these jobs in the background?  I've seen it been advocated for in other threads as a straightforward approach to running larger scheduled tasks - set a 'throttle' of how many ids to fetch and let the actual end-user client requests fire it as they run the scripts.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado: yes, seems like a good way to do these things

Comment: @frietkot: I am not really familiar with Tornado but judging from it's description, it does match the description of your situation. However solving the connections issue is only one part of your challenge; the bigger question is how to synchronize the workload between multiple threads of execution.

Comment: I'm just thinking, I have a little experience with nodejs. Would that not be a far better approach for me since i'm well known with javascript and php. So everyting is handled in the background by nodejs and the client fetches the results from mysql directly in php

Comment: @frietkot: If you can pull it off, why not. There are a couple of questions here on StackOverflow that address Node.js in regards to multiple threads of execution, for example [Long-running computations in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809165/long-running-computations-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

set the max execution time to zero and include it 
enclose your script in a inite loop:

```
set_time_limit(0);
while(true){
/your code
}
```

You should however include some way to end the process gracefully.
Some popular ways to do this is by checking if a env var was set or if a specific file exists.

```
set_time_limit(0);
while(true){
/your code
if(file_exist(KILL_SWITCH_FILE))break;
}
```

Another approach would be setting a flag when(in a filem,in a sql database,...) that your script is running and removing it when your done.
That way you can check if another instance of your script is still running.